# Weird error on transactions -> using NonQuery getting Reader must be closed

Tags: c#, transactions, database, datareader, npgsql

I'm developing a client in C# and POSTGRESQL.

It needs to parse some texts and insert data in the tables correctly, so we have a parsed which gives me a Dictionary for each tables (4 at the moment).

**So we have a thread which insert in a queue those dictionaries on a ConcurrentQueue.**

Now, we have two timers:

1) **every 10 seconds commit an opened transaction and recreates one**

these are the methods:

```
    void transactionTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(Logger.LogType.ERROR, ex);
                Rollback();
            }

            Transaction();
        }
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        if (trans != null)
        {
            trans.Commit();
            trans.Dispose();
            trans = null;
        }
    }
    public void Transaction()
    {
        if (dbCon == null || (dbCon != null && dbCon.State != ConnectionState.Open))
            dbCon = Connection;

        if (trans == null)
            trans = dbCon.BeginTransaction();
    }
    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (trans != null)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            trans.Dispose();
            trans = null;
        }
    }
```

2) **pick one hundred of data on the queue and do a huge insert** ( not 100* insert by just one by using paramereters like this:

```
    insert into Tabletest1_HandsData( handDataId, handData) values( @handDataId0,   @handData0),( @handDataId1, @handData1),( @handDataId2, @handData2),( @handDataId3, @handData3) ....
```

by using this helper

```
    public bool Insert(String tableName, Dictionary<String, object> data, bool usingTransaction = false)
    {
        Boolean returnCode = true;
        var sql = GetSQL(tableName, data);
        try
        {
            int rowsUpdated = -1;
            var conn = (!usingTransaction) ? Connection : dbCon;
            DbCommand mycommand = GetCommand(conn, sql);
            GetCommandByDictionary(mycommand, data);
            rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (!usingTransaction)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(Logger.LogType.ERROR, ex);
            returnCode = false;
        }
        return returnCode;
    }
    protected override void GetCommandByDictionary(DbCommand cmd, Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        foreach (var val in data)
            (cmd as NpgsqlCommand).Parameters.AddWithValue(val.Key.ToString(), val.Value);
    }
```

So, we parse and insert on a queue, then every 3 seconds we pick 100 of these and insert, and every 10 second a transaction is committed and recreated

My error is that ExecuteNonQuery is giving me:

```
    There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

Why is that happening?

I may take this opportunity to ask you, how can I do better? please feel free to insult me, I have tried a lot ot stuffs

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Are you using the command object to read data from the database in the GetCommandByDictionary method? If so, are you remembering of closing the returning datareader?

Comment: On the other side, I think it would be much cleaner if you simply used the following block of code for your worker thread: OpenConnection(); getdatatobeinserted();insertdata(); I think this is much better, simpler and give you a much higher level of concurrency and you would be able to launch any number of worker threads which would do the same thing independently (assuming, of course your getdatatobeinserted() accepts concurrency). You also wouldn't need to do all those checks about transaction, connection state etc. I hope it helps.

Comment: Also, the insertdata() method would wrap the actual insert inside a transaction. Or if it is needed, you could wrap getdatatobeinserted() and insertdata() calls in a transaction.

Comment: 1st comment: Nope, a parser gives me a Dictionary from a text given by IO, no DataReader is being used :(

Comment: 2nd comment: Yes, you're right, I already did like that but performances were unsatisfactory, so I tried to get better performances by using a lot of inserts in just one transaction

Comment: 3th comment: No, as I said, getdatatobeinserted is not called from DB, so I don't need to wrap it in a transaction. InsertData is using the connection opened by a previous InsertData if present, otherviwse is using one, and this mean it's opening that connection every 30 seconds ( then the timer commit transaction and opens a new one)

Comment: By the way, As I'm getting unsatisfactory performances also with this approach, I'm trying with using 4-5 already created functions to do this job.. Should it get better?

Comment: I think you should give a try in the bulk insert support of Postgresql. There is an example about how to do that with Npgsql in our manual: http://manual.npgsql.org

Comment: Another possibility would to change how you are creating your insert and instead of using parameters, you could create directly the insert string. I'm saying that because parameter substitution is a O(n) procedure and so you may be paying a performance penalty by using so many parameters.

Comment: I can't do bulk from a file with CopyIn, there's some parsing before

Comment: Using Parameters is fundamental for avoid "Encoding" issues and misleading characters and types :(

Comment: Francisco, I appreciate help like that from a NPGSQL developer, thanks you very much ;) I'm trying another approach, I've normalized tables and now got 4-5 tables, got 4-5 functions to insert data into these tables, should be much much faster.. If I've understood good I do not need to make "prepared inserts" and "start transactions" by using functions, right?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes. you don't need to start transactions or prepared inserts. Unless you need to guarantee that all your inserts are done or none at all. Then you would need to wrap your function calls inside a transaction. And indeed, by using functions and normalized tables you should get a much better performance.